# C Linux How you passing Argument to another program?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fork, exec

I want to create another process in C.
But i cant figure out how to pass the argument to the other one,
Using **fork()** , **exec()**
here's my code

**sls.c**

```
   int main() {
    void start_game (const char* file_name,int N,int max_lives)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int child_status;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid!=0){
        wait(&child_status);
    }
    else{
       if(-1 == execl("./player","player",&file_name,&max_lives,(char *)NULL))
       {
       perror("execlp() failed");
       return 1;
       }
    }
  int r = 1+rand()%max_lives;
}
    return(0);
}
```

I need to pass **file_name** and **max_live** to ***player.c***
so ***player.c*** can read the same file

**player.c**

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

pid_t child_pid = fork();
int child_status;
int sidekick_amount = (int)getpid%5;

void read_ints (const char* file_name)
{
 // Normal read file stuff here 
}


if (child_pid!=0)
{
    wait(&child_status);
}
else
{
    execlp("","-l",NULL);
    printf("Exec error\n");
    exit(-1);
}

   int lives = argv[2];
   printf("\nAt pos 0: Player %d has %d lives , %d sidekicks and 
   \n is ready to start ",(int)getppid(),lives,sidekick_amount);

    read_ints(file_name);
    return (0);
}
```

after reading the file and set thr amount of **sidekicks**. 
***player.c*** need to spawn the ***sidekick.c*** process for **sidekick_amount**
as ***player.c*** child . but i cant get the **file_name** and **lives** form the ***player.c***

***sidekicks.c***

```
enter code here
```

**out put**

```
At pos 0: Player 25477 has -5703328 lives , 1 sidekicks and is ready to start
```

thanks for all helps and all the answer are really appreciated

Comment: Program arguments must be strings. `max_lives` is an `int`.

Comment: And `file_name` is a pointer to a string, but `&file_name` is a pointer to the pointer. You need to pass the string.

Comment: You shouldn't have functions inside functions. I think that's a GCC extension, not standard C.

Comment: thanks a lot , now i want to check if my **file_name** is passing correctly in ***player.c*** ,is there a function to do it ?

Comment: The file name will be in `argv[1]`. I don't know what you mean by "passing correctly". You should just try to open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the integer `max_lives` to a string so you can pass it as a function argument. And when you're passing the file name, just pass the string itself, not the address of the pointer.

```
void start_game (const char* file_name,int N,int max_lives)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int child_status;
    pid = fork();


    if(pid!=0){
        wait(&child_status);
    }
    else{
        char max_lives_str[20];
        sprintf(max_lives_str, "%d", max_lives);
        if(-1 == execl("./player","player", file_name, max_lives_str, (char *)NULL))
        {
           perror("execlp() failed");
           return 1;
        }
    }
    int r = 1+rand()%max_lives;
}
```